# New 16.04 install, screen goes blank at random

Tags: screen

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 alongside no other OS. After I login, my display will go black and the system will not respond to any input. It will happen at random times, never in the same fashion twice. Sometimes when this happens my monitor will toggle very quickly between display found and not found. When the display does go black the system is not recoverable and must be restarted.

I've reinstalled twice and the same issue occurs.

I have a Intel Core i7-4790K for my CPU and a MSI Radeon R9 390 for my GPU.

Comment: search additional drivers and select your radeon model  in driver list after apply it. need internet connection for this operation

Answer (score 0):

which graphics drivers are loaded? Can you show the output of dmesg?
I believe that your R9 is using open source amdgpu driver.
In my laptop (R6 APU + R7 GPU) I also have many issues related with the amdgpu driver and kernel 4.4 combination. In my case I found several issues in dmesg related to amdgpu and R7 card.
If you could take the risk try the following:

- Install mesa-utils package
- Run the following command: DRI_PRIME=0 glxgears. To test if HD 4600 is working.
- Run command: DRI_PRIME=1 glxgears. To test if R9 is working. Be advice that in my case this caused the system to freeze.
- Install kernel 4.6 mainline (at your own risk).
- Compare new dmesg output versus previous.
- Run both glxgears commands again.

In my case kernel 4.6 improved the overall experience with amdgpu, now system freezes are mostly gone.

Good luck.